# Using mapply in a function to detect outliers more than 3sd from the mean returns incorrect values

Tags: function, mapply

I wrote a function that is supposed to return for each variable in a dataset a list of values that are more than 3sd apart from their column-mean. Therefore, I used mapply to compare for each single value in the dataset, whether its absolute value is more than three times larger than the sd of the respective variable it belongs to. The function works, however, it gives me a bunch of "outliers" that are not outside of this cutoff. Where might I have gone wrong?

```
findOutlier <- function(data, cutoff = 3) {

## Calculate the sd
sds <- apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)

## Identify the cells with value greater than cutoff * sd

result <- mapply(function(d, s) {
which(abs(d) > cutoff * s)
}, data, sds)
result
}
```